# Attach csv file to mariadb

Tags: mariadb, data-warehouse

Is it possible to access a csv file directly with the csv storage engine without going through the trouble of `load`ing it first?
We deploy a data warehouse where during load CSV files are read into a temp table and then insert the content in production fact tables. I wonder if we could just pass the `load into` and "directly go to <s>jail</s> insert"?

Comment: Like [load data infile](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/load-data-infile/), or  [connect with TABLE_TYPE=CSV](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect-files-retrieved-using-rest-queries/).

Comment: @danblack that looks promising, very promising. In fact it might me the answer to my question, need to investigate though. Than will provide my own answer. Thanks!